# Is a canonical morphism from the wedge sum to the product monic? A section?

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, monomorphisms

Let $C$ be a category with a terminal object $\ast$. For two pointed objects, define their wedge sum $c\vee d$ as the pushout
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\ast @>>c_0> c \\
@VVd_0V@VV\iota_cV \\
d @>>\iota_d> c \vee d
\end{CD}
$$
$\iota_c$, $\iota_d$ are sections.

Using the universal properties of $c \vee d$ and $c \times d$, we can now define a canonical map $c \vee d\overset{n}\to c \times d$ such that
$$\pi_cn\iota_c = 1_c,\ \pi_dn\iota_d = 1_d,$$ $$\pi_dn\iota_c = d_0\ast_c,\ \pi_cn\iota_d = c_0\ast_d,$$
(where I'm using $\ast_x$ as a shorthand for the morphism $x\to\ast$).

> Is $n:c \vee d\to c \times d$ a section? Is $n$ monic?

The answer is yes when $C=Set$, and I suspect it's very basic, or false, in general...

Comment: For groups, $c\vee d$ is the free product and $c\times d$ is the direct product. The map is the quotient map moding out by the cartesian $[c,d]$, which is not one-to-one in general, so it cannot be monic or the right inverse of a map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in general.

In $\mathsf{Group}$, every element is pointed, with zero object the trivial group. The wedge is just the free product $G*H$, and the product is the direct product $G\times H$.

The map $n$ you describe is the map $n\colon G*H\to G\times H$ obtained by moding out by the *cartesian subgroup*,
$$[G,H] = \langle [g,h]\mid g\in G,h\in H\rangle.$$
If $G$ and $H$ are nontrivial, then the map has nontrivial kernel (since no nontrivial element of $G$ commutes with a nontrivial element of $H$ in $G*H$). Thus, $n$ cannot be monic (in this category, monic is equivalent to one-to-one), and hence cannot have a right inverse, so it is not a section either.

On the other hand, in an abelian category you get an isomorphism.